# How to implement browser based Queue backed by indexeddb or localstorage?

Tags: javascript, queue, indexeddb, web-worker

I'm looking for a Browser based queue data structure, backed by persistent storage (localStorage or indexeddb) that can be used in JS.

My use case is for an offline app where it should use the queue to communicate with a server once it comes back online.

Ie, something like rails delayed_job or resque, but for the browser.

It would support an API like this:

```
Queue.Enqueue(() => { // do something  })
```

The queue would dequeu execute the function (in the background like a webworker or something hopefully) and poll for new entries periodically.

How would I implement this?

Comment: Have a look at service workers

Comment: Service workers seem like they can help with offline.  Not sure how they would help syncing with a server?

Comment: I think normal js arrays can do the job. if the array is emptied, you can replace it with {push:function(){}) to react live...

Comment: makes me wonder what's wrong with arrays? you can add functionality to them as needed...

Comment: The data needs to persist and survive offline

Answer (score 4):

I had the same need.

At first, I thought to implement that persistent queue backed by a WebSQL storage, but then I saw that the WebSQL standard is being discontinued by W3C:

https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

Finally, I implemented it using and IndexedDB storage. I created an object store with an autoincrement key generator, so I can simply add items to the queue calling:

```
objectStore.add(item)
```

And you can get a cursor to iterate over all queue items simply doing:

```
objectStore.openCursor()
```

By default, the cursor iterates the elements in increasing order of keys. As the keys are autoincremented at insertion, we are getting items in a FIFO order.

You can find more info on Indexed DB here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic in-browser localStorage queue, it works with jStorage, Store.js, or simpleStorage. Requires jQuery, and the Groucho localStorage manager.

https://github.com/tableau-mkt/jqueue

Comment: Link returns 404 now in September 2022